# Image is not uploading on server

Tags: php, android, post

Here is the function that uploads file (I use it in asynctask).
I took this code from examples on stackoverflow:

```
  public  JSONObject postFile(String fileName) throws Exception {
        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost post = new HttpPost(SERVER);
        MultipartEntityBuilder multipartEntity =
    MultipartEntityBuilder.create();
        multipartEntity.setMode(HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE);
        multipartEntity.addPart("file", new FileBody(new File(fileName)));
        post.setEntity(multipartEntity.build());
        HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);
        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
        is = entity.getContent();
        // response.getStatusLine();  // CONSIDER  Detect server complaints
        try {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    is, "UTF-8"));
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
            is.close();
            json = sb.toString();
            Log.e("JSON", json);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
        }

        // try parse the string to a JSON object
        try {
            jObj = new JSONObject(json);            
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
        }

        // return JSON String

        entity.consumeContent();
        client.getConnectionManager().shutdown();
        return jObj;

    }
```

php-file that handles post request:

```
if ($_FILES){
    $uploads_dir = 'uploads/';
    $uploadname = $_FILES["file"]["name"];
    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $uploads_dir.$uploadname))
    $response["success"] = 1;
else
    $response["success"] = 0;
echo json_encode($response);
     file_put_contents("log.txt",serialize($_FILES));
}
```

The image is not uploading. It gives everytime success "0".

Here is the log.txt file:

```
a:1:{s:4:"file";a:5:{s:4:"name";s:12:"IMAG0284.jpg";s:4:"type";s:24:"application/octet-stream";s:8:"tmp_name";s:36:"/home/autost02/.system/tmp/phplsAIRP";s:5:"error";i:0;s:4:"size";i:623552;}}
```

Comment: your upload handling is horrible. You don't check for actual success - failures will STILL popuplate $_FILES, leading to a false positive success. You're directly using the `['name']` parameter to generate the server-side filename, and do not validate the upload at all, so you're opening your server to a COMPLETE remote compromise.

Comment: thanks. what do you recommend?

Comment: the problem is solved

    if ($_FILES){
     $uploads_dir = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/uploads/';
     $uploadname = $_FILES["file"]["name"];
     if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $uploads_dir. $uploadname))
        $response["success"] = 1;
    else
        $response["success"] = 0;
    echo json_encode($response);
      file_put_contents("log.txt",serialize($_FILES));
    }